# Не работают кнопки "закрыть" и "закрепить" в панели задач Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое с любой программой. Если нажать на крестик в миниатюре то закроется, но это очень не удобно.

Всё что я мог пытаться то это искать информацию в интернете, увы, ничего не нашёл.

Windows 10 Pro x64 22H2
Установлена 6 дней назад

Comment: видимо за 6 дней умудрились сломать, либо изначально был установлен не чистый официальный образ, а например какая нибудь кривая сборка